# Is there a way to make .NET 6 applications to run on specific .NET 6 runtime version

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, target-framework

I have .NET6 application and I want to run this application on a specific .NET6 runtime version.

Let's say I have 2 .NET6 runtimes installed on my machine, i.e. 6.0.21 and 6.0.26. I want my .NET6 application to run on 6.0.21 runtime NOT on 6.0.26. It is always taking the latest 6.0.26 runtime only. How do I achieve this ?

I tried below 2 options to achieve this but didn't help,

- By setting `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>6.0.21</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` in the csproj file
- By adding global.json file with below entries

```json
{
  "runtime": {
    "version": "6.0.21"
  }
}
```

Please note that to identify the runtime used by application, I added below line of code in the application which tells what is the runtime used. Currently it is displaying 6.0.26.

`RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`

Kindly let me know if there is any other way to achieve this?

Comment: May we ask _why on earth_ you want to do this?

Comment: _"It is always taking the latest 6.0.26 runtime only."_ - because when you install .NET SDK updates the runtime gets updated too. Only major versions (and preview versions) of SDKs (and their runtimes) are retained during updates. The **only** way to permanently bind a .NET application to a specific .NET runtime is by doing a _self-contained_ deployment - and once it's built it's a binary so you can't make any further changes to it. However, the fact you're asking this question in the first places sets of many alarm-bells in my head...  there can't be any good reason why anyone would do this.

Comment: @Dai, you can manually install .net runtimes, so various versions can coexist, you can run `dotnet --list-runtimes` to see them.

Comment: @shingo Yes, but the fact that _the default behaviour in .NET_ is that updates automatically uninstall previous versions upon installation is a strong hint that we're not meant to keep old versions around...

Comment: @Dai It's not a problem with .net installation. Such a requirement exists, imagine that, when you receive a crash log reported by a client and the user is using an old version of the runtime, you naturally need to try it on that old runtime.

Comment: @shingo Right - but in that case I'd spin-up a new VM to repro it in and install the .NET runtime version in there; there's no way I'd be installing that locally on a dev box - and none of that requires me to rebuild my application for that .NET version either. That's why I can't think of a good reason for the OP wanting to do this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `.runtimeconfig.json`, note that *rollForward* must be set to *Disable*

   ```
   "runtimeOptions": {
       "framework": {
         "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
         "version": "6.0.21"
       },
       "rollForward": "Disable"
   }
   ```
2. Use command line option `--fx-version`

   ```
   dotnet --fx-version 6.0.21 <YOUR DLL>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy your app as a self-contained which means the the runtime selection occurs at the publish time (not run-time) [read about here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#self-contained-deployments-include-the-selected-runtime).

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>5.0.7</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or via the cli:

```
dotnet publish --self-contained true /p:RuntimeFrameworkVersion=6.0.21
```